# Using class objects in std::vector

Tags: c++, std

What is better -

```
std::vector<MyClass*>
```

or

```
std::vector<MyClass>
```

?
I mean, will the second option store objects in heap anyway?
Which one is faster and cleaner?

Comment: It very much depends on your requirements. As for using raw pointers, you should avoid it as much as possible, in favour of smart pointers like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector<MyClass>` shall be preferable in most cases. Yes, it will store objects in heap (dynamic storage) by default `std::allocator`.

The advantages are that objects are automatically destroyed on vector destruction and are allocated in single contiguous memory block reducing heap fragmentation. So this way it's cleaner.

Also this way is faster because it could minimize memory allocation operations. Vector will preallocate storage before constructing objects, so for N objects it will be M allocation operations and N constructor call, N > M (the bigger is N - the greater is difference). If you create objects manually and place them to vector by pointers it will lead to M allocations and N constructions, M = N + X, where X is vector storage allocations. And you always can minimize vector memory allocations if you know number of stored objects - using `std::vector::reserve()`.

On the contrary using `std::vector` of pointers will require you to destroy objects manually, e.g. calling `delete` for dynamically allocated objects. This is not recommended. Such containers shall be used only as **non-owning**. Objects ownership shall be maintained externally in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the second version will store the objects on the heap too, but in a more compact form, namely an array of `MyClass`.

In the first form you must allocate *and* deallocate your objects, while `std::vector` will do this for you in the second version.

So, as always, it depends on your needs and requirements. If you can choose, take the second form:

```
std::vector<MyClass>
```

it's much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.  Storing copies of your class in the container is easier to work with, of course, but you need to run the copy constructor every time to save an instance to the container which may be problematical.  Also, your container cannot store anything but that one class - in particular it cannot store other classes that are specialised ( inherited ) from your base class.  So, in general, you usually end up having to store pointers to the class.

There are snags with storing pointers.  However, to get the best of both worlds, consider using boost::ptr_vector instead, which has the advantages of smart pointers without the overhead.

Comment: `but you need to run the copy constructor every time to save an instance to the container which may be problematical` no you don't. Copy constructor only upon resize, otherwise copy-assignment. And even  you'd get move construction in most cases. Also, since inheritance isn't used that terribly much in C++ (compared to e.g. java where you really can't get around it) the requirement to support it doesn't pop up all the time either.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<MyClass>` will store objects on the heap (probably), `std::vector<MyClass*>` will store your pointers on the heap (probably) and your objects wherever they were created. Use `std::vector<MyClass>` whenever applicable, if you need to support inheritance `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>` again when applicable. If your vector isn't supposed to own the objects an `std::vector<MyClass*>` can be useful, but that's rarely the case.